# TypeORM Migration: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to generate a migration with TypeORM by using this command:

```
npx typeorm migration:generate -n Mock
```

However, each time that I run this command I get the following error:

```
Error during migration generation:
/home/raphael-dodobirdai/projects/typeorm-cc/ormconfig.ts:1
import { ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at ConnectionOptionsReader.<anonymous> (/home/raphael-dodobirdai/projects/typeorm-cc/node_modules/typeorm/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.js:120:46)
    at step (/home/raphael-dodobirdai/projects/typeorm-cc/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/raphael-dodobirdai/projects/typeorm-cc/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
```

I have a `ormconfig.ts` file with the configuration who look like this:

```js
import { ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";

import { Banker } from './src/entities/Banker';
import { Client } from './src/entities/Client'
import { Transaction } from './src/entities/Transaction'

export const ormconfig: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'xxxxxx',
  password: "yyyyyy",
  database: 'typeorm',
  entities: [Client, Banker, Transaction],
  synchronize: false
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1561#issuecomment-363562251

Answer (score 0):

You need to run typeorm with ts-node because now it's getting confused about what it should do. Despite TypeORM being a so-called Typescript library, the javascript still peeks through everywhere.